# Trying to upload images in cakephp and save the path in the database

Tags: php, cakephp

I need to allow a user to upload an image and I want that image to be saved in the directory *(webroot/uploads)* and also I would like the database to store the file path of the image.

I am getting this error: `Warning (2): mb_strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given [CORE\src\Validation\Validation.php, line 742]`

**`adaugare.ctp`**

```html
<div class="masiniSh form large-9 medium-8 columns content">
    <?= $this->Form->create($masiniSh, array('enctype'=>'multipart/form-data')) ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Adauga anunt') ?></legend>
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->control('marca', array('required'=>false));
            echo $this->Form->control('denumire', array('required'=>false));
            echo $this->Form->control('versiune', array('required'=>false));
            echo $this->Form->control('combustibil', array('required'=>false));
            echo $this->Form->control('cilindree', array('required'=>false));
            echo $this->Form->control('putere_maxima', array('required'=>false));
            echo $this->Form->control('consum_urban', array('required'=>false));
            echo $this->Form->control('consum_extraurban', array('required'=>false));
            echo $this->Form->control('consum_mixt', array('required'=>false));
            echo $this->Form->control('tractiune', array('required'=>false));
            echo $this->Form->control('cutie_viteze', array('required'=>false));
            echo $this->Form->control('numar_usi', array('required'=>false));
            echo $this->Form->control('pret', array('required'=>false));
            echo $this->Form->control('km', array('required'=>false));
            echo $this->Form->control('an_fabricatie', array('required'=>false));
            echo $this->Form->control('tel', array('required'=>false));
            echo $this->Form->control('nume_proprietar', array('required'=>false));
            echo $this->Form->control('locatie', array('required'=>false));
            echo $this->Form->control('imagine', array('type'=>'file'));
        ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
```

**`MasiniShController.php`**

```javascript
public function adaugare()
{
    $masiniSh = $this->MasiniSh->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $masiniSh = $this->MasiniSh->patchEntity($masiniSh, $this->request->getData());

        if ($this->MasiniSh->save($masiniSh)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The ad has been saved..'));

            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The ad could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }

        if (!empty($this->data)) {
            //Check if image has been uploaded
            if (!empty($this->data['MasiniSh']['imagine']['name'])) {
                $file = $this->data['MasiniSh']['imagine']; //put the data into a var for easy use

                $ext = substr(strtolower(strrchr($file['name'], '.')), 1); //get the extension
                $arr_ext = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'); //set allowed extensions

                //only process if the extension is valid
                if (in_array($ext, $arr_ext)) {
                    //do the actual uploading of the file. First arg is the tmp name, second arg is
                    //where we are putting it
                    move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], WWW_ROOT . 'uploads/' . $file['name']);

                    //prepare the filename for database entry
                    $this->data['MasiniSh']['imagine'] = $file['name'];
                }
            }

            //now do the save
            $this->MasiniSh->save($this->data) ;
        }   

    }
    $this->set(compact('masiniSh'));

}
```

P.S. imagine field is set as `varchar(255)` in the database

The problem is that when I click the submit button it appears that error. I found that if I comment the `maxLength('imagine', 255)` from `MasiniShTable.php` this error disappear, but it gives me another error: **The provided value is invalid.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you're trying to mix Cake 3.x code with some older version, maybe you found something online and tried to integrate it? Updated version below with some inline comments. Note that it's untested, but it should be close!

```
public function adaugare()
{
    $masiniSh = $this->MasiniSh->newEntity();

    // This is the new way of checking for $this->data
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        // Get a copy of the posted data for easier use
        $data = $this->request->getData();

        //Check if image has been uploaded
        // Note: the array keys here may not be exactly right, use pr($data) to look at it and make any required corrections. I've made a guess that MasiniSh isn't needed now.
        // Note2: it would be a more "Cake" solution to move this if block to the beforeMarshal function of the MasiniSh table class
        if (!empty($data['imagine']['name'])) {
            $file = $data['imagine']; //put the data into a var for easy use

            $ext = substr(strtolower(strrchr($file['name'], '.')), 1); //get the extension
            $arr_ext = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'); //set allowed extensions

            //only process if the extension is valid
            if (in_array($ext, $arr_ext)) {
                //do the actual uploading of the file. First arg is the tmp name, second arg is
                //where we are putting it
                move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], WWW_ROOT . 'uploads/' . $file['name']);

                //prepare the filename for database entry
                $data['imagine'] = $file['name'];
            } else {
                // You probably want to unset the imagine key from the data here, and maybe delete the temp file?
            }
        }

        //now update the entity and do the save
        $masiniSh = $this->MasiniSh->patchEntity($masiniSh, $data);

        if ($this->MasiniSh->save($masiniSh)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The ad has been saved..'));

            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The ad could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $this->set(compact('masiniSh'));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Greg Schmidt has already answered the question, but I'd like to add some pieces of advice. Files belong to the data layer and it would be better to work with them in Table/Entity classes. In my app, I use a technique which I borrowed from this component [cakephp-upload component](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/cakephp-upload). Firstly you need to add a custom DB type. In my case, it's called `FileType`. Then you need to map this new type to a field where you want to store your filename. These steps will give you an ability to work with the field as with an array in the `beforeSave` method. It will make your controller's code much cleaner because you'll move uploading logic to a Model. I've made [a Gist for you here](https://gist.github.com/yakubenko/32af536e2bd103b52b56db9ef9eb9ea3). I hope you get the idea and it helps you in your project.